# Parsing data with Gson multiple classes

Tags: json, gson

I used http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create Java bean classes from a JSON page which I am trying to parse and it generated 6 classes. Now I am stuck on how to tell GSON to map the data to those classes. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: hi, have a look a this [example](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/) if you don't want to use the  default gson data parser, you can specify you own by creating a `JsonDeserializer` or a  `TypeAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Foo foo2 = (Foo)gson.fromJson(json, Foo.class);
```